# Difference between GenerationType.AUTO and GenerationType.SEQUENCE using same sequence

Tags: hibernate, jpa, oracle11g, hibernate-mapping

Consider a scenario :
I'm using oracle 11g and have a sequence named MYSEQ_SEQ

[image]

if i have given the id in 2 different ways in my POJO class

**Case 1:**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "my_seq" )
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq", sequenceName = "MYSEQ_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@Column
private Long id;
```

**Case 2:**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq" )
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq", sequenceName = "MYSEQ_SEQ")
@Column
private Long id;
```

My questions is on creating a new object will both works in the same way?
Is there any difference in GenerationType.SEQUENCE and GenerationType.AUTO in this case?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier)  : 
JPA defines five types of identifier generation strategies:

**AUTO -** either identity column, sequence or table depending on the underlying DB

**SEQUENCE -** sequence

So in theory there is no difference since for in your case you're using Oracle  then the JPA provider (including hibernate) will create a sequence, although i'm not sure if `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "my_seq" )` will be accepted. But hey you can test it and see for yourself

Comment: woops my bad i edited my answer but it's still more or less the same.
Thanks for the observation